# Añadir código PHP dentro de un objeto JSON

Tags: php, json, jsonobject

Mi problema es este. Tengo un sitio multilenguaje usando objetos JSON y AJAX. En JSON guardo las traducciones por idioma y con AJAX en un archivo JavaScript uso las propiedades HTML "key" para saber dónde va cada traducción.

Estoy haciendo conexiones a bases de datos para login de usuarios, por lo que estoy trabajando con
documentos .php, no .html.

El problema es que en uno de los textos incluyo un vector SVG en medio párrafo y, como tengo que traducir el párrafo entero, tengo que incluir el vector SVG en el objeto JSON.
index.php

```html
<p class="lang" key="txt"></p>
```

lang.json

```json
{
    "es":{
    "txt" : "Texto que tengo que traducir. <?php require 'imagen.svg'; ?> También contiene un SVG en medio."
    },
    
    "en:{
    "txt : "Text that I have to translate. <?php require 'imagen.svg'; ?> It also contains an SVG in the middle."
    }
}
```

archivo.js

```javascript
$.getJSON("lang.json", function(json)
{
    //Lenguaje por defecto de la página
    sessionStorage.setItem("lang", "idioma")
    if(!localStorage.getItem("lang"))
    {
        localStorage.setItem("lang", "en");
    }
    let lang = localStorage.getItem("lang");
    let doc = json;

    $('.lang').each(function()
    {
        $(this).html(doc[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });//Each

    $('.flagLgs').click(function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem("lang", $(this).attr('id')) ;
        let lang = $(this).attr('id');
        let doc = json;

        $('.lang').each(function()
        {
            $(this).html(doc[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });     //Each
    });     //Funcion click
});     //Get json AJAX
```

Al final se traduce bien el texto, pero el archivo svg no se muestra, así que deduzco que JSON no reconoce la instrucción `<?php require 'imagen.svg'; ?>`. ¿Cómo podría llamar un archivo con PHP dentro de un objeto JSON?

No llamo al vector con un `<img src="imagen.svg">` porque tengo clases dentro del SVG con los que le doy estilos en CSS y trabajo con ellos en JavaScript.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tendrias que crearte tu propio sistema de plantillas para eso, e interpretar ese código embedido, no creo que valga la pena... ¿y si simplemente divides ese string en dos y dejas el codigo PHP entre medio en tu script PHP?

Comment: Es decir, sustituir esto: `<p class="lang" key="txt"></p>` por esto `<p><span class="lang" key="txt1"></span><?php require 'imagen.svg';?><span class="lang" key="txt2"></span></p>`

Comment: Por cierto, solo por si no te habias dado cuenta... si todo el texto lo rellenas con javascript dudo que eso sea SEO friendly y que se indexen correctamente las páginas en los buscadores.  Yo miraria de hacerlo desde PHP para que esas referencias a varios idiomas fueran resueltas cuando muestras el HTML final y no mientras la página se carga, pues los indexadores no acostumbran a ejecutar el javascript de las páginas... no se si me explico

Comment: Dado que la imagen es la misma, lo correcto aquí sería otorgar al objeto, **independientemente del idioma** una propieda (vamos a llamarla `img`) con la URL o lo que sea de la imagen, y usar esa propiedad ` img` en cualquier traducción. Tu objeto quedaría así: `{ "img": "laImagenQueEsComunATodos",
    "es":{
    "txt" : "Texto que tengo que traducir. También contiene un SVG en medio."
    },
    
    "en":{
    "txt" : "Text that I have to translate. It also contains an SVG in the middle."
    }
}`